# Completeness implies Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

As Completeness property of $R$  implies Monotone Convergence Theorem, Does its converse also hold? And can we generalize in to $R^{n}$ also?

Comment: What completeness property of $\mathbb R$ do you have in mind? 
That every Cauchy-sequence is convergent? That every bounded set has a supremum? or somthing else?

Comment: Your first question is duplicate at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90127/tfae-completeness-axiom-and-monotone-convergence-theorem.
For your second question, since $R^n$ does not have a total order for $n\geq2$, there seems to be no apparent generalizations.