# Monotone Convergence Property $\iff$ Least Upper Bound Property

Tags: ordered-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an arbitrary ordered field that satisfies **Monotone Convergence Property** then **$\mathbb{F}$ is Order Complete**.

**Order Completeness Property:** 
If $S \subset \mathbb{F}$ is bounded above, then $\exists \ c \in \mathbb{F}$ that is an upperbound of S and for every upperbound $b$ of S, we have $c \leq b.$

**Monotone Convergence Property**
Every monotone bounded sequence in $\mathbb{F}$ is convergent in $\mathbb{F}$.

---

I am not posting anything new. The answers were given in parts
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977099/monotone-convergence-property-iff-order-completeness-in-an-arbitrary-ordered)
and
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90127/tfae-completeness-axiom-and-monotone-convergence-theorem).

I have just brought it together for my own future reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Monotone Convergence Property $\implies$ Archimedean Property.**
   Let's assume $\mathbb{F}$ is not archimedean,  $\exists$ $c \in \mathbb{F}$ with $n<c$
   for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{F}}$. 
   By assumption $(1,2,...)$ must converge,say to $r \in \mathbb{F}$.
   $\implies$ $(0,1,2,...)$ also converges to $r$.
   Subtracting the two sequence we find (1,1,1,...) converges to 0, which is absurd. 
   Therefore $\mathbb{F}$ must be Archimedean.
2. Let $(\phi \ne)A \subseteq \mathbb{F}$ which is bounded above in $\mathbb{F}$, with $U$ being the set
   of upperbounds of $A$ in $\mathbb{F}$. 
   **Want:** To find an lub for $A$.

We now move on to build a few tools in order to prove the existence of $\operatorname{lub} A$.

3. **Claim 1:** $\{u-\varepsilon: u \in U\}=:U- \varepsilon \nsubseteq U$,
   for all $\varepsilon (>0) \in \mathbb{F}$.

   Let $\varepsilon>0$. 
   Let $U-\varepsilon \subseteq U$, Now we use induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{F}}$. 
   If $U-n\varepsilon \subseteq U$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{F}}$.
   then $U-(n+1)\varepsilon=(U-\varepsilon)-n\varepsilon$ $\subseteq U-n\varepsilon$ $\subseteq U$.
   $\implies$ $U-n\varepsilon \subseteq U$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{F}}$.
   Hence by Archimedean Property we have $\mathbb{F}= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U-n\varepsilon \subseteq U$,
   which contradicts $A \neq \phi$.
4. **Claim 2:** $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U-\frac{1}{n} \subseteq U$.

   Let $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U-\frac{1}{n}$ and let $(x<)y \in \mathbb{F}$.
   By archimedean property $\exists$ $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{F}}$ such that $x+\frac{1}{n} <y$. 
   $x \in U-\frac{1}{n}$\pause $\Rightarrow$ $x+\frac{1}{n} \in U$\pause $\Rightarrow$ $(x+\frac{1}{n}<)y 
      \notin A$. 
   $y$ is chosen arbitrarily, so $x$ is an upperbound of A, i.e $x \in U$.
5. **Claim 3:** $U-\frac1n$ $\subseteq$ $U-\frac1m$ for all $m \le n$.

   $m \le n \Rightarrow \frac1n \le \frac1m$. 
   $x \in U-\frac1n$ $\Rightarrow$ $x+\frac1n \le x+\frac1m$ $\Rightarrow x+\frac1m \in U$ $\Rightarrow x 
      \in U-\frac1m$.
6. **Corollary:**

   Let $n_k$ be any increasing sequence in $\mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{F}}$ then
   $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \left(U-\frac{1}{n_k}\right)$ =
   $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(U-\frac{1}{n}\right) \subseteq U.$
7. **Claim 4:** If $x \in \mathbb{F}$ with $x \notin U-\frac1n$, then
   $x<y$ for all $y \in U-\frac1n$.

   Let $u-\frac1n<x$ for some $u \in U.$ 
   Then $x-(u-\frac1n)>0$ $\implies u+x-(u-\frac1n) \in U$
   $\implies x \in U-\frac1n$, contradiction.
   Hence $x$ is less than every member of $U-\frac1n$.

Now we proceed in creating an increasing sequence so that we can apply Monotone Convergence Property.

8. Let $x_1\in (U-1) \setminus U$ ($\ne \phi$ by Claim 1)

   $x_1\notin U$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_1 \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U-\frac{1}{n}$.(from Claim 2) 
   so $\exists$ $n_1>1$ such that $x_1 \notin U-\frac{1}{n_1}$.
   Let $x_2 \in \left(U-\frac{1}{n_1}\right) \setminus U$.
   Then $\exists$ $n_2>n_1$(from Claim 3) 
   such that $x_2 \notin U - \frac{1}{n_2}$.
   Again consider $x_3 \in \left(U-\frac{1}{n_2} \setminus 
      U\right)$ and so on.
   This yields an increasing sequence $(1,n_1,n_2,...)$ in $\mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{F}}$(from Claim 3)
   and an increasing sequence $(x_k)$ in $\mathbb{F}$
   (from Claim 4,3) such that 
   $x_k \in \left(U-\frac{1}{n_{k-1}}\right) \setminus U.$ 
   Then $(x_k)$ is bounded above by each element of U. 
   $\implies$ $(x_k)\rightarrow x \in \mathbb{F}$.(M.C.P)
   $\implies$ $x \le u$ for all $u \in U$.

Remains to show that $x \in U$

9. Let $x_k \leq x$ for all k and $x_k \in \left(U-\frac{1}{n_k}\right)$
   $\implies x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \left(U-\frac{1}{n_k}\right) = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(U- 
      \frac{1}{n}\right) \subseteq U$, i.e $x \in U$. 
   Therefore $x$ is the smallest element in $U$, which means $x=\operatorname{lub}A$.\

   Hence for any nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb{F}$, $\operatorname{lub} A \in \mathbb{F}$
   i.e $\mathbb{F}$ is Order Complete.